# 「ようとしない」と「ことがある」の違い

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I’m right now learning the pattern 「ようとしない」 but I can’t tell the difference on a negative statement using 「ことがある」.

> 「彼は、自分のことは言おうとしない。」
> 「彼は、自分のことについて話すことがない。」

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. 彼は、自分のことは話そうとしない。
2. 彼は、自分のことについて話すことがない。

His *unwillingness* is explicitly expressed in the first sentence. ～(よ)う is a *volitional* form, after all. Maybe he has some shady background he wants to hide. The second sentence is simply saying such a thing does not happen. It may be that he has nothing interesting to tell, or no one is interested in him.